# Send email from @my-domain.com using SendGrid in Azure

Tags: azure, smtpclient, sendgrid

I have my web app working in azure. What I would like is to be able to send emails from xxx@mydomain.com. Is that possible using SendGrid?
For example, if I use gmail's smtp, emails are sent from the email address specified in the NetworkCredentials user name, even if in the MailMessage I use a different email address.
If I use SendGrid instead, will emails come from the user name created by azure or will I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will be able to send email from whatever address you want, just specify the correct from address (e.g. `xxx@mydomain.com`) when sending the email.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I'll try it and let you know

Comment: Won't these sorts of emails be flagged as spam? You're basically faking the from address.

Comment: In short, no. SendGrid "Whitelabeling" sets up `SPF` and `DKIM` to make us an "allowed" sender, which does _a lot_ to prevent mail from getting marked as spam. For customers who are not whitelabeled, SendGrid does "fake" the address, in that we're not a designated sender. However, we do have other things in place that prevents that mail from getting marked as spam.

Answer (score 1):

**You will need to use what SendGrid calls "Whitelabels":**

[image: SendGrid Whitelabel]

**To access this page, log into https://app.sendgrid.com/ then click on Settings > Whitelabels > Domains:**

[image]

**SendGrid will then ask you to enter 3 CNAME records to prove that you own/ have authorised access to that domain.**